# mysql count query gives 1

Tags: mysql, sql

I mistakenly run query

```
SELECT count(*) table_name
```

to learn row count. **It gives 1 as result**. Do you know what is the meaning of this result "1"?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

Simple.

The **table contains 1 record**.

Basically `COUNT` returns the number of records found on the table.

- [COUNT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count)

Comment: Sorry, I wrote it wrong. I forgot to write "from" keyword in select statement.